# Cannot read property 'toJSON' of undefined + backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I am really new to backbone, and in a world of confusion behind it. Right now I am trying to render a view of a single person, preferably without iterating through the entire collection, using the collection.get() method.

Here is the user collection:

```
App.Collections.UserCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: "/users",
    model: App.Models.User,

    initialize: function(){
        console.log('users collection');
    },

});
```

The user model:

```
 App.Models.User = Backbone.Model.extend({
        rootURL: '/users',
        initialize: function(){
            console.log('User model being generated');
        }

    });
```

the Users View (all users):

```
App.Views.Users = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: "body",
        model: 'user',

        initialize: function(){
            console.log('User view rendering');
            this.collection.fetch();
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.addAll);
        },
        clearDiv: function(){
            var container = $('#render-area');
            $('body').removeClass('homepage');
            $('#main-nav').fadeIn(100);
            container.empty();
            this.addUser();
        },
        addUser: function(){
            var current_user_model = this.collection.get(currentUser);
            var user = new App.Views.ViewUser({ model: current_user_model });
            $('#render-area').append(user.el);
        },

        events: {
            'click #view-profile' : 'clearDiv'
        }

});
```

and the viewUser view (single user):

```
App.Views.ViewUser = Backbone.View.extend({

        initialize: function(){
            console.log("single user view");
            this.template = HandlebarsTemplates['user_profile'];
            this.render();
        },  
        render: function(){
            $('#render-area').html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        },
});
```

I thought that I was grabbing the single user model in the Users view, and passing it to the ViewUser view with these lines

```
var current_user_model = this.collection.get(currentUser);
var user = new App.Views.ViewUser({ model: current_user_model });
```

But it seems that I am not. Any help and/or explanation is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you checked that there is anything in your model before passing it to your view ?

Comment: I would bet that there isn't, however I am not sure how to remedy that.

Answer (score 2):

did you check the `this.collection.get` is return an object?
Maybe it can not fetch the `currentUser`?

before render the view you should

a) check the model is a valid model before calling the view and render a "not found" view  or
b) in the view check if the model is valid and render a "not found" view
c) or you can handle it in handlebars template

Example A (untested):

```
var current_user_model = this.collection.get(currentUser);
if (current_user_model) {
    var user = new App.Views.ViewUser({ model: current_user_model });
} else {
    new AppViews.ViewUserNotFound();
}
```

Example B :

```
App.Views.ViewUser = Backbone.View.extend({

        initialize: function(){
            console.log("single user view");
            this.template = HandlebarsTemplates['user_profile'];
            this.templateNotFound = HandlebarsTemplates['user_profile_not_found'];
            this.render();
        },  
        render: function(){
            if(this.model) {
                $('#render-area').html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            } else {
                $('#render-area').html(this.templateNotFound());
            }
        },
});
var current_user_model = this.collection.get(currentUser);
var user = new App.Views.ViewUser({ model: current_user_model });
```

Example C:

```
App.Views.ViewUser = Backbone.View.extend({

        initialize: function(){
            console.log("single user view");
            this.template = HandlebarsTemplates['user_profile'];
            this.templateNotFound = HandlebarsTemplates['user_profile_not_found'];
            this.render();
        },  
        render: function(){
            if(!this.model) {
                this.model = new this.model(); // create model with defaults
            }
            $('#render-area').html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        },
});
var current_user_model = this.collection.get(currentUser);
var user = new App.Views.ViewUser({ model: current_user_model });
```

all examples untested..

hope this helps a little bit,
best Carsten

Comment: thank you so much Carsten, I have actually abandoned Backbone for this particular project as I am just too new at it and under a deadline, but I definitely appreciate you showing me a way to test for what is going on and it is a technique I will be trying out in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do that:

```
App.Views.Users = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: "body",
        model: 'user',

        initialize: function(){
            console.log('User view rendering');
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.addAll);
        },
        clearDiv: function(){
            var self = this;
            this.collection.fetch({
               success: function() {
                   var container = $('#render-area');
                   $('body').removeClass('homepage');
                   $('#main-nav').fadeIn(100);
                   container.empty();
                   self.addUser();
               }
            });
        },
        addUser: function(){
            var current_user_model = this.collection.get(currentUser);
            var user = new App.Views.ViewUser({ model: current_user_model });
            $('#render-area').append(user.el);
        },

        events: {
            'click #view-profile' : 'clearDiv'
        }

});
```

Comment: Thanks Francois, I will give this a try